# Enable only createdAt time stamp and ignore updatedAt timestamp in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to create some records into table with only the createdAt column filled. I want the updatedAt column to not exist how ever when i create a model it automatically generates the createdAt and updatedAt timestamps.

I tried to use `timestamps : false` but the createdAt column contains empty values.

```
const MyTable = sequelize.define(
  'my_table',
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true,
    },
    person_name: {type: DataTypes.STRING(255),allowNull: false},
    created: {type: DataTypes.DATE,allowNull: true},
  },
  {
    tableName: 'my_table',
    timestamps: false,
    createdAt: 'created',
  },
);
```

Is it possible to fix this issue in the model itself without doing any change in the query ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [the documentation on Init](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-init), you'll wanna leave the timestamps feature turned on, but configure your model to not use `updatedAt`.

Here's an edited version of the options object in your sample code that should give you what you are looking for:

```
  {
    tableName: 'my_table',
    updatedAt: false,
  }
```

NB: The docs say "Timestamps must be true", which might indicate why it wasn't working the way it is in the sample you provided.

Cheers!